# Start Installing iOS App with link

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following function in a controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{language}/apps/{application}", defaults={"application":"all"}, name="apps")
 */
public function indexAction( $application )
{
    $url['app'] = "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://www.xxx.xx/appfiles/App.plist";

    switch ($application) {
        case "app":
            return new Response($this->generateUrl($url['app']));
            break;

        default:
            return $this->render('AppBundle::app.html.twig',
                array(
                    "app" => $url['app']
                )
            );
            break;
    }

}
```

The application is a iOS-App.

Wenn I view the Link in my html.twig-file

```
<a href="{{ app }}">MBS-App installieren</a>
```

the installation of the app will start on the iPad or the iPhone. But wenn I try to make a new Response, then the string would be viewed on the browser, but no action starts on the tablet.

How should i change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redirect to that URL instead of returning a response with it:

```
    case "app":
        return $this->redirect($url['app']);
        break;
```